# Translate page on X axis then scroll back to be at same view

Tags: html, css, ios, mathjax, mathml

I have a use case where I want to translate the page on X axis by some amount , then scroll the page by the same amount to be on the same view as in the start .

It's working perfectly on all devices except for IOS ( I think Mac only ) where there's a flash . the problem isn't showing always ( in IOS ) but only when the page containes some Mathjax content ( Mathjax is used to render math sysmbols , it uses something called MathML  which uses some custom html tags )

here's the site now : https://little-bo-peep-leptos-v2.fly.dev/article/ch_1
when you're on phone you can click on blue circle ( or any shapes ) to do what's explained above . try on an Iphone to see the problem

If you try on this page : https://little-bo-peep-leptos-v2.fly.dev/article/ch_2 , which doesn't have any Mathjax , the problem doesn't appear